# Вызов функций Qt5 C++

Tags: c++, qt

Есть код:

```
InitializeScenario::InitializeScenario()
    : Scenario(Task::InterfaceList()
            << new Task::TemplateCopy
            << new Task::AddPackage
            << new Task::CommitPackage(QStringLiteral("Package initialized"))
              )
{
}
```

`<< new` - как я понимаю это создание объектов? Как называется подобная инициализация? Дайте ссылку на вики/статью/книгу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `Task::InterfaceList()` возвращает некий объект, у которого перегружен `operator<<`, вероятнее всего это `QList`. Выполняя этот оператора происходит добавление объект в список. Аргументами этого оператора являются `new Task::TemplateCopy`, `new Task::AddPackage` и т.д. `new T` это создание объекта в куче(heap) с использованием конструктора по умолчанию и возврат указателя, на вновь созданный объект. Это эквивалентно следующей записи `new Task::AddPackage()` или `new Task::AddPackage{}`

Comment: Т.е. другими словами: создавая объект InitializeScenario, явно задаем параметры конструктору Scenario, т.к. это базовый класс: class InitializeScenario: public Scenario? И какой тег на код?))

Comment: Ответ на первый вопрос: да. `И какой тег на код?` - этого я не понял

Comment: Спасибо.
В сообщениях выделять текст, как сделали это Вы, в предыдущем комментарии с тексом "И какой тег на код?"

Comment: Так код выделяется специальными одинарными кавычками. Они находятся там где Ё на клавиатуре, только в английской раскладке. Так выделяется однострочный код. Для многострочного кода есть кнопка в редакторе, когда вопрос/ответ создаёте. Там всё видно.

Comment: Если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, помечайте его решённым.

Answer (score 0):

`<< new` - это две различные конструкции. Это не какая то "особая конструкция.

Рассмотрим вот эту часть кода

```
Task::InterfaceList() << new Task::TemplateCopy << new Task::AddPackage << new Task::CommitPackage(QStringLiteral("Package initialized"))
```

Ее можно переписать на более классический код так

```
auto t = Task::InterfaceList();
t.push(new Task::TemplateCopy);
t.push(new Task::AddPackage);
t.push(new Task::CommitPackage(QStringLiteral("Package initialized")))
```

(это очень схематический код).

У объекта Task::InterfaceList() есть переопределенный оператор `operator<<`, который по факту делает добавление в список (я обозначил как push).

В целом - обычный с++ код + немного Qt магии.